# Cannot import Drawer component from antd react library

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd components in my react app. Out of all components, I am facing difficulty in importing and using only the `Drawer` component. All other components are working fine. My code is rather straightforward.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Layout, Menu, Button, Drawer } from 'antd';

export class MyDesign extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button />                              <-- works fine
        <Drawer title="Test" visible={true}>    <--- doesn't work
          <p>Some contents...</p>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This causes the following console warning, issued from within `webpackHotDevClient`

```
'antd' does not contain an export named 'Drawer'.
```

which indicates that the issue is with how my app imports antd, and definitely not with antd itself. I was unable to reproduce the issue on a small testcase on codepen, using the same latest stable version of `"antd": "^3.7.3"`.

What might be going on? Is there some sort of selective project-wide import happening that I need to override?

Comment: Very interesting. [It works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/ry7mqmr574). Have you tried removing `node_modules` and reinstalling everything? `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install`

Comment: Mmm.. With this info is pretty dificult to say what is happening. Are you sure you are using the 3.x version? The Drawer components doesnt exist in the 2.x version. Also check if the folder drawer under node_modules/antd/lib/ exists. I've check with your version and everything works fine!

Comment: `package.json > "dependencies" > "antd"` shows `"^3.7.3"`. Double checked.

Comment: Hey your suggestion worked. I also restarted the server for good measure. But I am pretty sure that I had not changed anything within the node_modules directory. Or maybe I did. How else could this be possible? Very surprising!

Comment: It might be that you installed an older version, added `"^3.7.3"` to `package.json` without actually installing it, or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an older version of `antd` in your `node_modules`, and that you have only updated the `package.json` to contain the newest version without reinstalling it.

You can remove `node_modules` and reinstall everything to get all the versions of every dependency listed in `package.json`:

```
rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install
```